# Describe the graph of g(x) using the terminology: increasing, decreasing, local maximum or local minimum points and the following information:

Tags: calculus

Describe the graph of g(x) using the terminology:
increasing, decreasing, local maximum or local minimum points and the following information:

ƒ'(x) < 0 when x < 2;

ƒ'(x) < 0 when x = 2;

ƒ'(x) < 0 when x > 2;

f(0) = 3, f(1) = 0, f(3) = 0.

Now as an example of how to answer the question I was given this question

g′(x) > 0 when x < -1;

g′(x) = 0 when x = -1;

g′(x) < 0 when x > -1;

g′(x) is a linear function.

and the solution to that is this

**g(x) is increasing when x < -1 and decreasing when x > -1. There is a local maximum at x = -1.**

I do not understand how this answer was achieved and how to achieve it on the f'(x) question.

And I have an explanation on how to solve questions like these and what I need know to solve them please?

Comment: Please check the statement of the first problem.  As written, it suggests that $f$ is strictly decreasing, which is impossible if $f(1) = 0$ and $f(3) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

While the derivative of the function indicates the slope of the tangent line at the point at which the derivative is being taken, derivatives reveal much about the behavior of the graph itself.

For simplicity, take the position versus time graph. The derivative of the position with respect to time is the velocity. So imagine that a ball is going up (positive). That means the position during this interval is increasing (becoming more positive). What is going on with the velocity curve? Well, for the ball to be increasing its position in the positive direction, it must have positive velocity.

Suddenly, the ball starts to turn around. At this instant, similarly to when you throw up a ball and it reaches its highest point, the derivative of the position curve is zero because there is no change in position with respect to time at that instance in time.

Then, the ball is falling down and its position, although *positive*, is *decreasing*. Thus, the velocity, derivative of the position w.r.t time, of the ball is negative.

So, if $g(x)$ is increasing whenever $x<-1$ and $g(x)$ is decreasing whenever $x>-1$, then this means $g'(x)>0$ for $x<-1$, $g'(x)=0$ for $x=-1$, and $g'(x)<0$ for $x>-1$.

Naturally, as in the ball example, whenever the derivative goes from positive to zero to negative, the point at which the derivative is equal to zero would be a local maximum. If it is the other way around, negative to zero to positive, we would have a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to know, the f′(x) indicates the slope of the tangent in point x. So you can image if the points are in the left side of x make f′(x) > 0 then it means the direction of the tangent upwards, so the f(x) will be increasing. 
On the other hand, if in the point x f′(x) = 0 then the tangent is horizontal and after that the tangent begins downtowards so f(x) decreasing after that. 
So, x is the local maximum value.
Hope this helpful.